# Wix Component needs Guid to be changed when branching application

Tags: wix, components, windows-installer, guid, wix3.5

My scenario is really straight forward:

I have a windows application with several files that lands in a "Program files..." folder. These files are divided into components depending on what kind of functionality there's in them. The files are mostly .net assemblies are not in any way global. They should only be used by my application. I use major upgrade when installing a new version.

Now I want to make a release v1.0 of the application and at the same time keep on working with v2.0. The two version which shall run side by side, so course I need to change the UpgradeCode. I also of course make a branch in my source control to manage the v1.0 and v2.0 tracks.

My question is: *Do I need to make new guids for all the components i v2.0?*. In the best of worlds there is no conflict between component in different msi-databases?

Best regards

// Henrik Carlsson

Answer (score 0):

Theres no need to change GUID. If you are going for a update WIX prefers that you change the Upgrade code GUID in wix file